# Can I upgrade a plugin to a specific version?

Tags: plugins, updates, upgrade

I am testing plugin upgrades on a staging instance before applying them to production. But if there are any delays in this process, I may end up being prompted to upgrade to a newer, untested version on production.

If prompted to upgrade a plugin, how can I choose an intermediary update, rather than the latest?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Using WP-CLI you can specify this as described in the [official documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/plugin/update/).

```
$ wp plugin update <plugin>
```

Using either of the following arguments

```
--minor
```

> Only perform updates for minor releases (e.g. from 1.3 to 1.4 instead of 2.0)

```
--patch
```

> Only perform updates for patch releases (e.g. from 1.3 to 1.3.3 instead of 1.4)

```
--version=<version>
```

> If set, the plugin will be updated to the specified version.

Comment: Any simple alternative for users without cli knowledge is https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rollback/

Answer (score 3):

You can also download specific versions from the plugin's SVN.

For example, imagine you wanted a specific version of the Yoast SEO plugin.

The plugin page for Yoast is is:

[https://wordpress.org/plugins/`wordpress-seo`/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/%60wordpress-seo%60/)

Note the highlighted section of the URI `wordpress-seo`

The SVN/Repo URI will be (notice the URI slug includes the highlighted section from above):

[https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/`wordpress-seo`/tags/](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/%60wordpress-seo%60/tags/)

The `tags` folder lists all the versions.

Comment: Could you give a short code snippet on how to do that? I for example don't know the first thing about SVN, as I have always been using Git

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward no cli method of easily upgrading / downgrading a plugin to  a specific version:

1. Click on "advanced view" on the right column of the plugin's page under the list of info - it will take you to a url like `https://wordpress.org/plugins/<plugin>/advanced/`
2. Find the "previous versions" section at the very bottom, select the version you want from the dropdown and download the zip file
3. Remove the current version's folder from `wp-content/plugins`
4. Extract the zip you just downloaded and copy the folder into `wp-content/plugins`
5. Verify on your site at `www.yoursite.com/wp-admin/plugins.php` that the version you wanted is now listed

That's it.